# Charge on capacitors in circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, charge

I have this circuit with defined components specifications:

- R1 = R2 = R3 = 100 kΩ
- C1 = C2 = 1000 μF
- C3 = 4700 μF
- U = 24 V

First question is to calculate the charge on each capacitor. I managed to do that and got Q1 = 0.008 As, Q2 = 0.016 As, Q3 = 0.0752 As.

Second question is asking to find the new charges right after you remove the power source and short its contacts. I figured that the sum of charges on all capacitors should remain the same but have no idea how to determine where the charge from each capacitor went where.

Please notice that I'm a beginner on this topic and thank you for help!

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first recommendation to you is to use a circuit simulator. Many free online simulators are available. The best way to cross check your answers is to compare with the simulation results.

Your charge calculations for the charge on each capacitor is correct.

Coming to the second question, you can redraw the original circuit (I have added node names A, B, C)

[image]

to the following

[image]

Assume B, C are 0V (i.e., ground). Now, first task is to find the voltage on node A as soon as B,C are shorted. This voltage like you said should be calculated by assuming that sum of capacitor charge is the same. Take into account the sign of the charge. For eg., since I have taken B, C as 0V, C1 contributes +0.008C charge at node A but C2 contributes -0.016C charge on node A. The total charge divided by the total cap gives the initial voltage on node A after shorting B,C.

Based on this new voltage on node A, you can compute how much is the new charge on each cap and the difference in the charge for each cap before and after shorting B,C is what has got redistributed from other caps to this one.
**Clue**: The cap with the highest charge will donate charge to the others.

Finally at t=infinity, all caps will discharge to 0V through the resistors.

Since this appears to be a homework problem, I am not giving the final answers.

Comment: Thank you for answer and sorry for long response time. The way you redrew your circuit really helped. The only thing I'm not sure is right is the way you calculated voltage between nodes A and BC because as far as I know you can't just divide total charge by total capacitance like you did. I calculated it by equalizing cap voltages (Q1/C1  =  Q2/C2 = Q3/C3) and it was quite easy than to get the voltage with a help of total capacitance calculated earlier. Then I calculated charges Q1=Q2=0.0124C and Q3=0.0583C, ofc rounded up.

Comment: @MatjažMeža, your charges calculation is correct. So, how did you get voltage at A as -12.4V? Total cap is 6.7mF. Total charge is +0.008-0.016-0.0752=-0.0832C . So, voltage at A w.r.t B,C = 0.0832/6.7m = -12.4V. This is what I meant

Comment: now I understand, I did it the longer way before by calculating charge on first capacitor first and that voltage out of that but your way is way faster.